# Different behaviour of same C#/.Net code in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

This code in C# works well and as intended,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("outbox,zip");

DelResParams delParams = new DelResParams();
delParams.PublicIds = list;
delParams.Type = "multi";

cloudinary.DeleteResources(delParams);
```

I actually need a PowerShell script, my conversion is as following,

```
$list = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

$list.Add("outbox,zip")

$deleteParams = New-Object CloudinaryDotNet.Actions.DelResParams
$deleteParams.PublicIDs = $list
$delteParams.Type = "multi"


$cloudinary.DeleteResources($deleteParams)
```

Now `$delteParams.Type = "multi"` says **Property 'Type' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.**

In PowerShell, all .Net assemblies are loaded properly and working well for rest of the script.

Type property is defined as, `string DelResParams.Type`

What I'm doing wrong actually?

Comment: Is 'Type' a 'reserved property' ?

Comment: @DrKoch I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Try using another name for the property...

Comment: @DrKoch, I've had a typo in $delteParams.Type = "multi" It should be $delete not $delte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your script:

```
$delteParams.Type = "multi"
```

You are missing an "e" in "delete". The dead giveaway here is that the `P`s in `Params` don't line up.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Thanks JLRishe.